# matplotlib with TkAgg backend doesn't work on Mac High Sierra

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython, macos-high-sierra, matplotlib-widget

I have a code for GUI(wxPython) that plots data and that works fine on Windows 7 machine:

- Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit
  (Intel)] on win32
- matplotlib.get_backend() returns TkAgg as the backend
- wx.**version**   '4.0.1'

However, it doesn't work for Mac OS High Sierra

- Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12)  [GCC 4.2.1
  (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
- matplotlib.get_backend() returns TkAgg as the backend
- wx.**version**   '4.0.1'

The symbol of python appears on the dashboard but nothing happens. No errors, no warning... nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, I found the problem. I realized that I import libraries for WxAgg

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FCW
```

Hence, it is not necessary that TkAgg backend is not working on my Mac OS High Sierra. However, I have forced backend to be WxAgg:

```
 matplotlib.use('WxAgg')
```

now the code is working fine.